# Selenium Python: Browser cannot load dynamically loaded data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape data using python selenium from this [website](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm). I can enter the variables for which I require the data but the browser doesn't seem to fetch the data when I send the key "Enter" which it seems to do in a normal browser. Any help is appreciated!

Code-

```
driver.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm')

instrument_type = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('instrumentType'))
instrument_type.select_by_visible_text('Index Futures')

symbol = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('symbol'))
symbol.select_by_visible_text('NIFTY 50')

radio_button = driver.find_element_by_id('rdDateToDate')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radio_button)


start_date = driver.find_element_by_id('fromDate')
start_date.send_keys('01-01-2019')

end_date = driver.find_element_by_id('toDate')
end_date.send_keys('01-01-2020')
end_date.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: a quick fix is to include time.sleep() between the different commands to allow the script to execute javascript andd load updated html

Comment: i tried it but the problem is even after manually clicking on the get data button in the chromedriver, it doesn't seem to do anything.